# How to get new list of points after threshold distance?

Tags: python, distance, threshold

I have a array with coordinates. I calculates the distances between all points. Now I only want to show the coordinates that have a distance above a certain threshold. How can I do this in python?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

dx = np.array([b-a for a,b in combinations (x,2)])
dy = np.array([b-a for a,b in combinations (y,2)])
all_distances = scipy.stats.pdist( np.array(list(zip(x,y))) )
all_distances

df3=all_distances[~(all_distances<=35)]
df4=all_distances[~(all_distances<=40)]
df5=all_distances[~(all_distances<=45)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.scatter(df3)
plt.ylabel('dy')
plt.xlabel('dx')
plt.show()
```

Below you see the point with all distances, but now I want a scatterplot with point that are above a threshold of 35

[scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXI0T.png)

Comment: Could you supply a minimal working example including all import and some data?

Comment: Yes, I added a scatterplot

Comment: Could you at lets say 10 values of x and y, where 5 should be plotted and 5 not?

Comment: If you have 10 values of x en y. You have 45 pairs with a certain distance and dx/dy coordinate. Now I want to skip pairs below or above a certain distance and plot their dx/dy point. How can I do this?

Comment: If dx and dy have the same length as all_distances you can do plt.scatter(dx[all_distances>35], dy[all_distances>35])

Comment: Thanks, this works!

Comment: Updated my answer and would be great, if you mark that as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you are looking for something like this

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

combinations = np.array([(1,2), (3,4), (5,8), (10,12)])

all_distances = pdist( np.array(combinations))
print(all_distances)
print(all_distances[all_distances>3])
```

You are able to do the same with other arrays to, so probably something like `plt.scatter(dx[all_distances>35], dy[all_distances>35])` solves your problem.

Comment: See the scatterplot. No all pair of nodes are plotted (each point have dx and dy value). Now I want to plot only the pair of nodes with a distance > 35. How can I solve this?